Angular - Why is my search bar not working well?
dashboard.component.html :
<div class="search-bar">
      <form class="search-form d-flex align-items-center" method="POST" >
        <input type="text" name="query" placeholder="Search" title="Enter search keyword" (keyup)="filterUsers($event)">
        <button type="submit" title="Search"><i class="bi bi-search"></i></button>
      </form>
    </div>

    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let user of users">
        {{ user.name }}
      </li>
    </ul>

dashboard.component.ts :
  users: any[] = [];
  filteredUsers: any[] = []; 

  firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: "",
    measurementId: ""
  };
  
  

 ngOnInit() {
    if (!initializeApp.length) {
      initializeApp(this.firebaseConfig);
    }
    const database = getDatabase();
    const usersRef = ref(database, 'users');
    
    onValue(usersRef, (snapshot: DataSnapshot) => {
      const data = snapshot.val();
      this.users = data ? Object.values(data) : []; 
      this.filteredUsers = this.users;
    });
  }


  filterUsers(event: any) {
    const searchTerm = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
    this.filteredUsers = this.users.filter(user => user.name().includes(searchTerm));
  }

After typing the username that I'm looking for , it's expected to show me the list of the users having that name , instead that doesn't happen and the page keeps reloading

This is because you are using an HTML form with a POST action that has the default action of submitting the form. At the same time, you don't need the submit button because you are performing the search every time you type a key into the text input.
    <div class="search-bar">
      <form class="search-form d-flex align-items-center">
        <input type="text" name="query" placeholder="Search" title="Enter search keyword" (keyup)="filterUsers($event)" />
      </form>
    </div>

    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let user of users">
        {{ user.name }}
      </li>
    </ul>

Making those few changes should allow the filter system to work.

it's not working , now whenever I log in / sign up it keeps reloading ( just one reload but it looks like it'll keep reloading forever ) even though I didn't type any username

Are you just typing or are you pressing enter to 'submit' the search?

even before typing anything it's reloading , just directly after logging in

does that still happen if you remove they keyup function?

yes in all cases

the prb is here : onValue(usersRef, (snapshot: DataSnapshot) => {
const data = snapshot.val();
this.users = data ? Object.values(data) : [];
this.filteredUsers = this.users;
});
and in filterUsers method cuz , when i removed both of them , the reload prb is gone , and if one of them is still there , the prb is still there

Consider replacing the form with a div
